# Which will Boone use better, a Sniper Rifle or an Anti Material Rifle?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

How effective is boone at using an anti Material rifle, compared to using a sniper rifle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boone needs armor that grants +1 to STR, such as power armor, to take advantage of the Anti Material Rifle, as the AMR has a STR req. of 8, and Boone starts out at a default of 7, so he will suffer a disadvantage.

If you can circumvent that obstacle and get power armor or armor that gives him STR, it's clearly better to take the Anti Material Rifle over the Sniper Rifle.

Of course though, remember your companions will require ammo to use weapons you give them, so if you give them an AMR, make sure to provide plenty of .50 ammo.

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Boone%27s_scoped_hunting_rifle 41.1 DPS vs http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Anti-materiel_rifle 49.3 dps.

Comment: What if i give him alcohol, as most alcoholic drinks add plus one strength

Comment: And is it cost effective, do the aadvantages out way the the cost disadvantages of the very expensive anti material rifle

Comment: @TheFoxSage You only get the STR bonus from alcohol if you consume it. Boone will not consume food or drinks, so you need armor that will grant that bonus.  Regardless, my personal choice is to give him the Gobi Campaign Sniper Rifle or just a regular one, the ammo is much more easier to get (.308 vs .50 for AMR), and allows him to spend more time at range